# From my desktop GitHub, how can I redirect commits and push to a new remote repo, cloned from orignal master?

Tags: github, github-desktop

Basically, I cloned a repo, remote to local, for a new project, and started working on the cloned files. I changed the directory, but not the local name from original master repo  to new locally cloned repo.

So I have 11 commits to 11 files that are set up to be pushed to original repo, but I dont want this. I've created a new remote repo and want to redirect these local commits to a new repo on remote.

One related question I have is,
if I can simply.just change the directory/path, do I need the original files on new repo first before push? Or can I push my local files with commits to an empty (new repo) on remote !